# Changing a desktop background programmatically

Tags: c++, c, background, desktop

Just as a fun project I want to recreate the Matrix rain for my laptop's background. I looked into how to how to do the Matrix rain and have plenty ideas of how to do that, but I haven't really found anything on changing or setting the desktop background programmatically. So, this is my question. **How can I change the desktop background programmatically?** I would preferably like to use C or C++ to do this, any help is greatly thanked!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/153075/setting-an-animated-gif-as-the-desktop-background-on-windows-7

Comment: Some trickery using [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) is how I've seen it done in the past. Hit up some google-fu and see what you find.

Answer (score 2):

Some excerpts from one of my programs:

In Windows 7, there is only one wallpaper file in the system. Therefore we save the current wallpaper in a temporary file and replace the wallpaper with our image. Later we restore the original file:

```
// Get the system's wallpaper filename from the registry
GetRegKeyStrHK(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Control Panel\\Desktop","WallPaper", szFilename, sizeof(szFilename));

// Now copy that file to a temporary file
CopyFile(szFilename, "C:\\myTmpWallpaper.bmp",FALSE);

// Then tell the system to use a new file (it will copy it to the old filename)
SystemParametersInfo (SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (LPSTR) szMyDesktopImage, 0);
```

Function `GetRegKeyStrHK()` is from my library and it gets the value (wallpaper filename) from the registry.

---

```
int GetRegKeyStrHK (HKEY hK, const char *szRoot, const char *szName, char *szValue, int iValueSize)
{
    HKEY hkResult;
    int  iKeyType, bufsize, result;

    if (RegOpenKeyEx(hK, szRoot, 0, KEY_READ, &hkResult)
                != ERROR_SUCCESS) return(FALSE);        // no such key

    bufsize=iValueSize;
    result= RegQueryValueEx(hkResult,szName,0, &iKeyType, (BYTE *)szValue, &bufsize);
    RegCloseKey (hkResult);

    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) return(FALSE);         // no such name/value pair or buffer too small
    return (TRUE);
}
```